# Jupyter widgets: How to use 'Button' to update content of 'Label' based on value of 'FloatText'?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, ipywidgets

I am unable to use widgets in Jupyter to make something that actually should be simple but I can't make it work: I want a GUI where the user presses a 'Button' to update the content of a 'Label' based on value of 'FloatText'

I tried many things to no avail. Here two examples:

Example 1:

```
from ipywidgets import FloatText, Button, Label, interact

t_str1 = FloatText( description='Strain in %:', value='3' )

b_cs   = Button( description='Compute Stress' )

t_str2 = Label( value='Waiting' )

display( t_str1 ); display( b_cs )

def compute_stress( x ):
    t_str2 = Label( value='Stress = ' + str(x+3)+ 'MPa' )
    display( t_str2 );
    
interact( compute_stress, x=t_str1 );
```

Result of example 1:

[image]

Example 2:

```
from ipywidgets import FloatText, Button, Label, interact

t_str1 = FloatText( description='Strain in %:', value='3' )

b_cs   = Button( description='Compute Stress' )

t_str2 = Label( value='Waiting' )

display( t_str1 ); display( b_cs ); display( t_str2 );

def compute_stress( x ):
    t_str2 = Label( value='Stress = ' + str(x+3)+ 'MPa' )
    
interact( compute_stress, x=t_str1 );
```

Result of example 2:

[image]

This is what I would like to obtain

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your button to work, you nedd to associate an `on_click` function to it. You then also won't need the `interact` function to do what you want. Additionnally, to ensure that the widgets appear in the layout you want, you can use `VBox`.
Here is what the code looks like when you implement these changes:

```py
import ipywidgets as widgets

t_str1 = widgets.FloatText( description='Strain in %:', value='3' )
b_cs   = widgets.Button( description='Compute Stress' )
t_str2 = widgets.Label(value='Waiting' )

vb=widgets.VBox([t_str1,b_cs,t_str2])

def on_click_compute_stress(b):
    t_str2.value='Stress = '+str(t_str1.value+3)+'MPa'

b_cs.on_click(on_click_compute_stress)

display(vb)
```

And the output gives:

[image]